# android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable"

Tags: java, android, xml, android-drawable

I have this line of code:

`mBgTransition = (TransitionDrawable) mSwitchBg.getBackground();`

the bg used to be a regular drawable,

but now it's a 9-patch

then I get this error:

`android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable"`

how can I make bg transition with my ninePatchDrawable?

It used to be like:

```
case CHECKED: {
    mBgTransition.reverseTransition(BG_TRANSITION_TIME);
}
case UNCHECKED: {
    mBgTransition.startTransition(BG_TRANSITION_TIME);
}
```

Comment: What did this guy do wrong to get a downvote? At least comment on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I fix this?

Don't try to cast a `NinePatchDrawable` to a `TransitionDrawable`. Neither one is a subclass of the other, so it won't work. The two are simply not interchangeable.

Instead, you need to cast `mSwitchBg.getBackground()` to a `NinePatchDrawable`.

> how can I make bg transition with my ninePatchDrawable?

You need to use your nine-patch drawables inside of a transition drawable resource file.

Thus you should have the following:

- Two nine-patch drawable PNGs representing the two states of the transition drawable
- One transition drawable XML file that references the nine-patches.
- One layout XML file (or code) that sets the background of your View to the transition drawable, **not** the nine-patch.

The transition drawable should look something like this:

```
<transition
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/my_nine_patch" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/my_second_nine_patch" />

</transition>
```

Comment: but then how can I do image transition?

Comment: thanks for you reply. That's exactly what I have in my project, but yet the ninepatch are miss scaled. is there a know issue?